# Increase a Div height based on another Div content and it's height

Tags: javascript, jquery

**[Current js fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/M35xJ/1/)**

I have two Div **.mainDiv** and **.sideDiv**.  **.mainDiv** has long content having toggle paragraph in it . When I click the  **Click to expand** text ,FULL paragraph shows up and the height of this content increases .

**WHAT I WANT** : When I press the **Click to expand** text, the .mainDiv height increases  and also .sideDiv height should increase equal to .mainDiv height . and when **Again** the main DIV decrease the height of .sideDiv also decrease .

Is there any way with jQuery to make that happen ? I am not good at jquery So I am finding it difficult to make it happen if someone help me with it would be great for me . and also sorry for bad English

Thanks

**HTML**

```
<div class="mainDiv">
<p class="click"> Click to expand </p>

<p class="hide">
    and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, 
    but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. 
    It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset
    sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
    desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker 
    including versions of Lorem Ipsum.

</p>    

</div>

<div class="sideDiv">
  <p>Should Expand this Div</p>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.mainDiv {
background-color:#ccc;
float:left;
width:200px;
}

.sideDiv {
background:yellow;
float:left;
width:200px;
height:auto;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.hide').hide();

$('.click').on('click', function () {
$('.hide').toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes , Please try this.

Demo :http://jsfiddle.net/M35xJ/5/

```
$('.click').on('click', function () {
    $('.hide').toggle();        
    $('.sideDiv').height($('.mainDiv').height());
});
```

More details : http://api.jquery.com/height/

Comment: Can you suggest me on this little more ? Like if I have many .mainDiv and .sideDiv and clicking each .mainDiv will increase it's .sideDiv height ? Example :http://jsfiddle.net/saifrahu28/M35xJ/9/

Is this possible ?

Comment: Yes it is possible . Currently you are using class as selector. So if you have more divs having same class, then it will select all and perform same action. Instead you can have IDs for every div and make a general way to identify the sub divs

Comment: Yes So I have to make same number of ID's as number of div I take . But I am wondering if the are 100 divs I have to take 100 ID's ? Is there any more Dynamic way ? So that what ever the number of the Div's will work ? Thank you For your valuable time you are give me

Comment: You can have an option to use `jquery parent`. It requires different id for different div. If you are creating html  manually then you must give different ID. If you are generating html using some program, then you can easily generate id. You need to identify the id of div which contains "click here" using jquery parent and find the next id (generate second div ID related with mainDiv like `smalldiv_mainDiv1` etc). So you can identify if you get the id of main div. just check this http://jsfiddle.net/YThmH/91/, it will give you an idea of jquery parent.

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your code

```
$('.hide').hide();

$('.click').on('click', function () {
    $('.hide').toggle();
    var x = $('.mainDiv').css('height');      // Added
    $('.sideDiv').css('height', x);           // Added
});
```

> [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/M35xJ/6/)

Answer (score 2):

I took this approach, which resizes when the toggle is complete.

```
$('.hide').hide();

$('.click').on('click', function () {
    $('.hide').toggle(0,function() {
        $('.sideDiv').height($('.mainDiv').height());
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/M35xJ/7/